# Node.js is installed but not working

Tags: command-line, software-installation, kernel, nodejs

Node.js is installed but not working. How to solve it?

```
$ nvm install node
Downloading and installing node v18.0.0...
Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v18.0.0/node-v18.0.0-linux-x64.tar.xz...
######################################################################## 100.0%
Computing checksum with sha256sum
Checksums matched!
Now using node v18.0.0 (npm v)
Creating default alias: default -> node (-> v18.0.0)
$ node -v
node: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by node)
node: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.25' not found (required by node)
node: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by node)
```

Comment: Here is how to install Node: https://askubuntu.com/a/1402894/566421

Answer (score 0):

From what I've read you could try `nvm install v10.13.0`

Comment: None of the conventional uninstall-install works. Actually from other questions here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1402934/all-ubuntu-commands-results-in-glibc-2-30-not-found it seems that the most cost-effective solution is to reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: Maybe if you use 32-bit that could be why, not sure though. :/

Comment: Ironically, as explained in the above link, your suggestion (and the suggestions of many web tutorials) is what may cause this problem in the first place. You are forcing the installation of an app of a version that you are not sure if it matches the version of your distro (and I don't know of some easy way to know which app version is okay for which distro version). And it may mess up your Ubuntu. They neglect to mention it in all those "How to install a specific version of xxx".

Answer (score 0):

Beginning with node v18.0.0, the build process has changed and Ubuntu 18.0.4 is no longer supported as [noted here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/42351).

You can move to a supported platform for this version, but your best bet is to just use the latest LTS which still supports Ubuntu 18.0.4.

```
nvm install --lts
```

You may want to change your default version as well.

```
nvm alias default {VERSION}
```

The command you are using `nvm install node` installs the latest development build. Unless you are contributing to the node.js project, it's probably not what you want.